# Return a total record count alongside a subset of data in MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, pagination

I have a fairly standard query that I use when I want to get a subset of data in MS SQL, for pagination of records.

What I'd like to do is also return a *total* record count in the same query, as efficiently as possible.

There are a few other questions on SO that address this issue, essentially getting a total count of records when using `ROW_NUMBER()` before returning the subset required.

These solutions don't seem to work for me, not least because in this particular case I am working with a *view*, and it seems that I cannot use `ROW_NUMBER()` without specifying a `TOP` value first; thus the total row count only consists of the subset.

Can anyone suggest a way of returning the total count given that I am running the following code on a view in SQL Server 2008?

```
DECLARE
     @PageSize    INT  = 10
,    @CurrentPage INT  = 1
;

WITH o AS
       (
             SELECT TOP (@CurrentPage * @PageSize)
                  [RowNumber]       = ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY [t_YourTable].[IndexedField] DESC )
             ,     [t_YourTable].[Field1]
             ,     [t_YourTable].[Field2]
             ,     [t_YourTable].[Field3]
             ,     [t_YourTable].[Field4]
             ,     [t_YourTable].[IndexedField]

             FROM  [t_YourTable]

             ORDER BY
                  [t_YourTable].[IndexedField] DESC
       )

SELECT
           [Field1]
       ,    [Field2]
       ,    [Field3]
       ,    [Field4]
       ,    [IndexedField]

FROM o

WHERE
      [RowNumber] BETWEEN (( @CurrentPage - 1 ) * @PageSize + 1 )
AND ((( @CurrentPage - 1 ) * @PageSize) + @PageSize)

ORDER BY
      [RowNumber]
```

If I were able to get rid of the `TOP` statement, I assume I could simply count the `RowNumber` field and return that as part of the result set - but SQL Server says I can't do that on a view.

Comment: I think SQL gives you an error if you use ORDER BY inside a View, the error can be avoided if you specify TOP.

Comment: That's correct - TOP is specified in my example, however this means that I cannot return the total record count based on the criteria... Unless I artificially set the TOP value extremely high - but that feels like a bit of a hack really.

Comment: You could remove TOP and ORDER BY and use ROW_NUMBER for pagination as you said in your question. Could that work, of course that would mean you'd need to change the client application.

Comment: I'm not sure I would be able to order the records if I went down that route.

Comment: You can order them by [Rownumber] but you need to do that in your application that uses this view and pagination - if I understand this correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I can get this working using `TOP (100) PERCENT`, which allows me to then count the rows in a sub select. I'm not sure how efficient this is, so I'd appreciate any feedback.

My code becomes:

```
DECLARE
     @PageSize    INT  = 10
,    @CurrentPage INT  = 1
;

WITH o AS
       (
             SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT
                   [RowNumber]       = ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY [t_YourTable].[IndexedField] DESC )
             ,     [t_YourTable].[Field1]
             ,     [t_YourTable].[Field2]
             ,     [t_YourTable].[Field3]
             ,     [t_YourTable].[Field4]
             ,     [t_YourTable].[IndexedField]

             FROM  [t_YourTable]

             ORDER BY
                  [t_YourTable].[IndexedField] DESC
       )

SELECT      (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM o) AS TotalRows
       ,    [Field1]
       ,    [Field2]
       ,    [Field3]
       ,    [Field4]
       ,    [IndexedField]

FROM o

WHERE
      [RowNumber] BETWEEN (( @CurrentPage - 1 ) * @PageSize + 1 )
AND ((( @CurrentPage - 1 ) * @PageSize) + @PageSize)

ORDER BY
      [RowNumber]
```